# Excel VBA UDF finding maximum spread between two assigned values and two ranges

Tags: vba, excel

made a similar post recently that I had to delete because I misphrased my question.  I'm trying to create an Excel VBA UDF in which each row of the assigned range is compared to an assigned value, and the maximum range in the series is derived.  Please note that both range1 and range2 will always be of equal length, and I'm only trying to perform the analysis on each unique row in the range.  For instance, the dateset below would have 4 comparisons, due to 4 rows, and the maxrangecheck result would be `180%`,

```
loop1 = 3
loop2 = 1000

range1  range2  range1 %    range2 %    maxrangecheck
5       882     67%         -12%                79%
6       842     100%        -16%               116%
8       869     167%        -13%               180%
2       859     -33%        -14%               -19%
```

And the code below is what I've devised - I know it doesn't work, but hopefully gives an idea for what I'm trying to do,

```
Function maxrangecheck(loop1 As Double, loop2 as Double, range1 As range, range2 As range)

Dim i As Range
Dim j As Range
Dim checki As Double
Dim checkj As Double
Dim spread As Double
Dim output As Double

For Each i In range1
    checki = i.Value - loop1

For Each j In range2
    checkj = j.Value - loop2

spread = checki - checkj

If spread >= spread Then
output = spread
Else:
output = output

Next j
Next i

maxrangecheck = output

End Function
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I describe the general algorithm for doing this on [this Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/85875/36565). Should be a simple VBA port.

Comment: If you want to loop like this `For Each i In range1` then `i` should be of type `Range`, not `Long`.

Comment: And how exactly do you get 78% as a result? I am missing something probably.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the maximum value in column 4?

Comment: @Comintern, thank you.  I should have mentioned I'm a very green programmer and am not sure I'll be able to adapt the Javascript, but having a look now.

Comment: @Vityata, changing the type now, thank you for pointing that out.  And the 78% is a rounding error, changing that as well.

Comment: Don't adapt the javascript - that's what I was reviewing ;-). Follow the link in my comment to [my implementation on ideone](http://ideone.com/hN0kUv).

Comment: @jcrizk, yes, that's all I'm trying to do.

Comment: @JoeJack you could just use Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(column 4) if that's all you're trying to do

Comment: Also `If spread > spread` is never going to work so output will always remain zero.

Comment: @SJR i was about to say that as my answer for why his code was never working lol

Comment: @jcrizk and SJR agreed, that has been changed.  The broader problem I'm having is that I have the 'j' loop within the 'i' loop - so all of the j values are compared against the first i value, and then the second i value, etc.  So I actually get 16 results in the loop, as opposed to the 4 that I'm trying to get.

Comment: Plus (1) you don't need two loops, just reference the relative cell in each range (2) shouldn't check j be the range2 value minus loop2 rather than the other way round?

Comment: @JoeJack If spread >= spread Then 

will always fire because spread = spread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It covers the points I made in comments as well as Vityata's. As it stands it will return zero if all the checks are negative so that may need to be changed.

```
Function maxrangecheck(loop1 As Double, loop2 As Double, range1 As Range, range2 As Range)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim checki As Double
Dim checkj As Double
Dim spread As Double
Dim output As Double

For i = 1 To range1.Count
    checki = (range1(i).Value - loop1) / loop1
    checkj = (range2(i).Value - loop2) / loop2
    spread = checki - checkj
    If spread > output Then
        output = spread
    End If
Next i

maxrangecheck = output

End Function
'a quick test
Sub x()

MsgBox Format(maxrangecheck(3, 1000, Range("A2:A5"), Range("B2:B5")), "0.0%")
```